# LibLinear + grid.py (LibSVM) for HOG training

Tags: python, computer-vision, svm, libsvm, liblinear

i've been training a HOG to detect objects with pretty good results thusfar using LibLinear. When i saw the grid.py python-script, included in the LibSVM package, i sort of recreated this by doing cross-validations with different C values.

However this script is trying different values for C and gamma but liblinear doesn't have a gamma parameter, is the bias parameter similar to LibSVM's gamma?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gamma is a parameter of the RBF kernel. LibLinear is an alternative (usually faster) formulation to C-SVM, using a Linear kernel instead. Thus, the gamma parameter is not used, while the C parameter is used because it comes from the C-SVM.

The grid.py script that comes with LibSVM uses the C-SVM formulation and the RBF kernel. So, to use it with LibLinear, you should disable gamma by passing "-log2g null" and update the path to the train/predict binaries of LibSVM on grid.py to the LibLinear ones.

For a better understanding, I suggest you read this [quick practical tutorial](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) written by the authors of LibSVM/LibLinear.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the gamma parameter was only used by the RBF kernel. I won't be using the grid,py script, this script as well as all these training tools use a text-file for input which can be easily 70 times slower than reading a binary file. I've written the C-finding in my main program which appears no longer needed when removing inconsistant negatives from the training data.